# find duplicated records in billions records

Tags: bitmap, record, long-integer

I've got ten billions records of a data, and each record have a field named ID.
The ID is in long format, something like:

```
217775404914720768
310426682752372736
214675181568921600
```

My task is to find duplicated ID in this dataset. I've tried Bitmap, seems it didn't work.
For BloomFilter, I'm concern it may cause error as my dataset is so huge.
So any better ideas?

Comment: What is the value range of the ids? Do you with "long format" mean that they are arbitrary 64 bit numbers, or are they limited by a max value much less than (2^64-1)?

Comment: let's assume here the value is 18 characters in length like the example above.

Comment: Can you use a database or do you have to implement it yourself?

Comment: I need to read the record, and implement it myself.

Comment: Why? Unless you have gigantic amounts of RAM or very much time to spend for the actual search, the problem is not at all trivial to solve.

Comment: I've found a tool called MapDB, and now running it to solve the problem. The collections in java didn't work.